# How to format numbers in HTML Body for automated emails on Google Apps Script

Tags: html, email, google-apps-script, automation, html-email

I'm trying to format numbers in the automated email I created on Google Apps Script. I'm pulling numbers from an existing Google Sheets. In the Google Sheets,  numbers are in the correct format (commas, up to 2 decimal points) ie. 123,456.78 - but when I call this data for the automated email, it ignores the number format in Google Sheets ie. 123456.7891011

Is there a way to make the numbers in my automated email follow the same number format? Or a way to use codes to impose number formats? FYI, I'm using HTML to bold, italicize and make paragraphs in my email body text.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method using google sheets that returns the displayed value:

```
function getCellValueWithFormat() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getRange(1,1);

  Logger.log(cell.getValue());
  Logger.log(cell.getNumberFormat());
  Logger.log(cell.getDisplayValue());}
```

[image: Picture of my logs]

Comment: If this answers your question don't forget to mark it as answer.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I'm a beginner like literally just started using Google Apps Scripts yesterday, can I just literally copy and paste it and it'll work? Or do I need to add in things in the parenthesis... call(?) the function? Could you give me some more detail? Thanks!

Comment: Depending on a method, it might or might not take in arguments. The parenthesis will always follow a method. Cell is a variable/object hence why no parenthesis are used here. 
Arguments that can be passed to methods can be viewed within google's documentation. I also recommand you turn content assist on from the edit menu(or simply ctrl+space).

Simply targeting the cell you need a value from and using the getDisplayValue() method should provide you with the desired output

Answer (score 1):

You could use Number.prototype.toFixed()

- [Number.prototype.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)